# How do I upgrade from 8.04 to 8.10?

Tags: upgrade, 8.04, 8.10

I have Ubuntu 8.04 and I am trying to use "update manager"
to upgrade to 8.10. The upgrade fails because of some problem
related to network/internet setting. The error I get is discussed
and a solution by hyperion is posted at:
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/50648

hyperion is referring to the settings in 
System-->Preferences-->Network Proxy

I have the option "Direct internet connection" selected.
Hyperion says that Ubuntu will upgrade if I choose "Manual proxy configuration".
The problem with this option is that I would have to fill in a lot of details
like HTTP proxy, Secure HTTP proxy, Port (8080?) and I dont know any of this.

I have a AT&T DSL line for my internet. I tried putting the Gateway address for
HTTP proxy, but it does not work.

Can anyone help me to get around this issue?

Comment: This might be a better fit for SuperUser or askUbuntu

Comment: @vik Why not just reinstall?

Answer (score 4):

You can download an Ubuntu alternate [iso](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download) then mount it. Go to the mounted iso directory and run the install script.

Comment: You need 10.04 or higher. Everything else is EOL.

Comment: @wojox Depends. If this is a server (which I don't think it is) then it's not EOL.

Answer (score 4):

Does your internet connection work (for example with the web browser)?

Ubuntu 8.04 is an LTS release so you can directly upgrade to 10.04. Start Software Sources, go to the "Updates" tab and under the "Release upgrade" section choose the "Long term support releases only". Then reload the package information, and try to upgrade again with the Update Manager. Ubuntu 8.10 isn't supported anymore that might be a reason why upgrade doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I really REAAALLLY recommend to not upgrade from 8.04 to 8.10 but download the Ubuntu 11.04 (If you are using the Desktop version) and backup what you need and just do it from the burned ISO. You will safe a lot of time, download sizes, etc..

I recommend reading this: [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-10-04-or-10-10-to-11-04) if it helps. But still recommend downloading the latest because you will need to upgrade from 8.04 -> 8.10 -> 9.04 -> 9.10 -> 10.04 -> 10.10 -> 11.04 and if my experience has taught me anything is that doing an upgrade, even if it looks nice it can sometimes create problems. For me the only version i have upgraded safely was from 10.10 to 11.04. But 8.04, 8.10, 9.04 and 10.04 had an error that i had to start from scratch. (Did not test 9.10 but i reckon it would have given me an error)